# Specifying order of guides changes the guide

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I manually specify the order of legend guides, the fill guide looks different. That's a surprising interaction. What I want is to specify that fill goes first, while preserving the kind of fill guide I get in the first plot.

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a plot
set.seed(123)
p <- expand.grid(x=1:10, y=1:10) %>%
  data.frame(fill=rlnorm(100)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=fill)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=x*y), shape=21) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

When print `p`, it looks like this:

```
p
```

[image]

But when I specify the guide order (which in this case doesn't even change the default order), the fill guide looks different (it's appears as a discrete scale instead of continuous, & with the direction reversed)

```
p + guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1),
           size = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image]

How can I specify fill order while preserving the kind of fill guide I get in the first plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, it's because `guide_legend` means a discrete legend (the second kind shown above). I should use `guide_colorbar`:

```
p + guides(fill = guide_colorbar(order = 1),
           size = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

now it works as expected